# how to switch on the elasticsearch stemming

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't know how to turn on the Elasticsearch English word stemming. I am sorry I didn't find out a clear example to do that.

Here is what I did

**Creating the index**

```
PUT /staff/list/ -d 
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "standard": {
          "type": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Adding document**

```
PUT /staff/list/jason
{
      "Title" : "searches"
}
```

**when I search for `search`**

```
GET /staff/list/_search?q=search
```

The result doesnt appear.

What index setting I should do to make the stemming works.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: how are you performing your search?

Comment: sry, just updated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the index, you are doing nothing (just re-declaring the standard analyzer).

The `standard` analyzer is the default that Elasticsearch uses, which doesn't stem any word.

You need to map the fields to their respective analyzers at your index creation ([mapping documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)):

```
PUT /staff -d
{
    "mappings": {
        "list": {
            "properties": {
                "Title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess [english analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) fits to your case (which uses the `standard` tokenizer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it work after I change the search by using ```query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "most_fields", 
      "query":    "search",
      "fields": [ "title", "title.english" ]
    }
  } ``` I dont know why ```q= ``` is not working

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the default Elasticsearch analyzer do not support stemming.
In order to support stemming you may need to create a custom analyzer.
Here is how you do it:

**Create the index and define an analyzer called my_analyzer**

```
PUT /staff
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "filter_snowball_en": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "English"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "filter_snowball_en"
            ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Configure mapping that assigns my_analyzer to list type**

```
PUT /staff/_mapping/list
{
  "list": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type":     "string",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index documents**

```
PUT /staff/list/jason
{
   "title": "searches"
}


PUT /staff/list/debby
{
   "title": "searched open"
}
```

**Search and stemmed results**

```
GET staff/list/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "title:opened"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
      {
          "_index": "staff",
          "_type": "list",
          "_id": "debby",
          "_score": 1,
          "_source": {
              "title": "open"
          }
      }]
   }
}
```

As you can see in the search results, `debby` document which contains the term
`open` was returned although we where searching for `opened`.

Hope that helps.